# Get id (undefined) of object

Tags: javascript

I have an code if I do console.log(resp)

I got to see  (see img) but when I do `console.log(resp[id]) of console.log(resp[{id}])`

[image]

I see undefined.

How can I access the id that is been created ?

```
    var request = gapi.client.request({
               'path': '/drive/v2/files/',
               'method': 'POST',
               'headers': {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
               },
               'body':{
                   "title" : name,
                   "mimeType" : "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                   "parents": [{
                        "kind": "drive#file",
                        "id": FOLDER_ID,
                    }],
               }
```

this is the code I use. the id is not the same id as id : FOLDER_id

how can I access that id ?

Comment: what is `resp` in your first sentence? nothing called resp in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your accessing the property the wrong way, try this

`resp.id` or `resp["id"]`

Note the second way is wrapped into quote to make it a string.

Comment: AHHH thnx it worked ( i will accept ur answer in 10(can't accept it right know)

Answer (score 0):

to access it you need to do this:

```
resp.id
```

when it is deeper inside just add thing for example the id that you didn't want to get:

```
request.body.parents.id
```